# How to smoothly transition the visible content of a web page with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page with different sections and I would like to change the visible section when you click on a section link.

```
    <div id="sections" class="col-md-8">
        <section id="pathogens" >
            <p>aaaaa</p>
        </section>
        <section id="population" >
            <p>bbbbb</p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Unexperimented as I am, I have achieved this with this little code.

```
function activateSection(section){
    $('#sections').children().hide();
    $('#'+section).show();

    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $('#menu li a.'+section+'').parent().addClass('active');
}
```

but that is not really smooth, the page is flickering that's not eye-pleasing.

I searched for recommended ways to do this but I didn't find anything specific to my problem.

Do you recommend using a plugin like [smoothState.js](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js)?

Thank you!

**IMPORTANT EDIT**:
I noticed the flickering is mostly due to the length of the content which is making the scrollbar appearing and disappearing quickly and thus changes the width of the page.

Comment: Please show relevant `HTML`.

Comment: Yes I recommend using a plugin, especially since you're not very experienced in this stuff. No need to reinvent the wheel imho.

Comment: Thanks. which plugins do you recommend for this? I'm also happy to learn and don't really like using plugins without need.

Answer (score 0):

Only have one visible section at a time and track which section is visible with a variable outside of the scope of the function. See the code below:

```
    var currentActiveSection = "pathogens";
    function activateSection(section) {
        $('#' + currentActiveSection).hide("slow");
        $('#' + section).show("slow");
        currentActiveSection = section;
        // only updated the relevant code above, also make any changes required to the code below 
        $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu li a.' + section + '').parent().addClass('active');
    }
```

Please note that you can play around with the `.show` and `.hide` parameters "slow", "fast" etc to get the desired effect. Alternatively use another jquery function like `.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut` to get a different effect.

If older browser support is not an issue for you, I suggest changing your setup completely and going with css3 transitions instead:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index.html#portfolio

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function activateSection(section){
    $('#sections').children().hide(); // or fadeOut() or sideUp()
    $('#'+section).fadeIn(2000); //or slideDown()

    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $('#menu li a.'+section+'').parent().addClass('active');
}

activateSection('pathogens') // or 'population'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sections" class="col-md-8">
        <section id="pathogens" >
            <p>aaaaa</p>
        </section>
        <section id="population" >
            <p>bbbbb</p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think what you are looking for is even easier than you think. Instead of using the show() function, why don't you instead call fadeIn('slow')?

Dependent on the actual look of the content, slideDown() and slideUp() functions could be called too.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 has a nice transition feature : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

the problem is that it deactivates the url hashtags